# Add new words to the lexicon for R sentiment package

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently doing sentiment and emotion analysis of Twitter's data using R sentiment package and need to add new words to the subjectivity and emotion lexicons used by the package as there are some words that carry specific sentiment and emotion in the topic that I analyze.

Does anyone know how to add words to the lexicon using the R sentiment package itself or any other R command? I have searched in the documentation but cannot find any means to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the subjectivity & emotion lexicon when read in (say, as csv) construct a data frame for you. Adding entries to a data frame can be done using the rbind() function.

> patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
> age <- c(25, 34, 28, 52)
> diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
> status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
> patientdata <- data.frame(patientID, age, diabetes, status)
> patientdata
  patientID age diabetes    status
1         1  25    Type1      Poor
2         2  34    Type2  Improved
3         3  28    Type1 Excellent
4         4  52    Type1      Poor
> patientID <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
> age <- c(50, 68, 56, 104)
> diabetes <- c("Type4", "Type5", "Type6", "Type7")
> status <- c("Poorish", "Improving", "Excellento", "Poorish")
> patientdata1 <- data.frame(patientID, age, diabetes, status)
> patientdata1
  patientID age diabetes     status
1        10  50    Type4    Poorish
2        20  68    Type5  Improving
3        30  56    Type6 Excellento
4        40 104    Type7    Poorish
> concatPD <- rbind(patientdata,patientdata1)
> concatPD
  patientID age diabetes     status
1         1  25    Type1       Poor
2         2  34    Type2   Improved
3         3  28    Type1  Excellent
4         4  52    Type1       Poor
5        10  50    Type4    Poorish
6        20  68    Type5  Improving
7        30  56    Type6 Excellento
8        40 104    Type7    Poorish
>

I simply added the weird types of diabetes to ensure that the 2 frames are distinguished. :-)
In other words, you can create our own csv, read it (thereby creating another data frame) & rbind them. Ensure that the columns of both data frames are in sync.

Comment: Hi Anand, thank you for the answer. It's so simple yet brilliant approach :)